# Spark job fails while filtering kafka messages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Need to check if event messages sent to `Kafka` are valid by checking if message has needed fields and if so, push data to `Elasticsearch`. This is how I done it:

```
object App {

  val parseJsonStream = (inStream: RDD[String]) => {
    inStream.flatMap(json => {
      try {
        val parsed = parse(json)
        Option(parsed)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => System.err.println("Exception while parsing JSON: " + json)
          e.printStackTrace()
          None
      }
    }).flatMap(v => {
      if (v.values.isInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]]])
        v.values.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]]]
      else if (v.values.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]])
        List(v.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]])
      else {
        System.err.println("EVENT WRONG FORMAT: " + v.values)
        List()
      }
    }).flatMap(mapa => {
      val h = mapa.get("header")
      val b = mapa.get("body")
      if (h.toSeq.toString.contains("session.end") && !b.toSeq.toString.contains("duration")) {
        System.err.println("session.end HAS NO DURATION FIELD!")
        None
      }
      else if (h.isEmpty || h.get.get("userID").isEmpty || h.get.get("timestamp").isEmpty) {
        throw new Exception("FIELD IS MISSING")
        None
      }
      else {
        Some(mapa)
      }
    })
  }

  val kafkaStream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc, PreferBrokers, Subscribe[String, String](KAFKA_EVENT_TOPICS, kafkaParams)
  )
  val kafkaStreamParsed = kafkaStream.transform(rdd => {
    val eventJSON = rdd.map(_.value)
    parseJsonStream(eventJSON)
  }
  )

  val esEventsStream = kafkaStreamParsed.map(addElasticMetadata(_))

  try {
    EsSparkStreaming.saveToEs(esEventsStream, ELASTICSEARCH_EVENTS_INDEX + "_{postfix}" + "/" + ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE, Map("es.mapping.id" -> "docid")
    )
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      EsSparkStreaming.saveToEs(esEventsStream, ELASTICSEARCH_FAILED_EVENTS)
      e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

I guess someone is sending invalid events (that's the reason why am I doing this check anyway), but `Spark job` doesn't skip the message, it fails with message:

> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 190, xxx.xxx.host.xx,
>   executor 3): java.lang.Exception: FIELD IS MISSING

How can I prevent it from crashing and to just skip message instead? It is `YARN` application, using:

```
Spark 2.3.1
Spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1
Scala 2.11.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```scala
throw new Exception("FIELD IS MISSING")
None
```

Just do this

```scala
None
```

Throwing this exception causes your program to terminate.

Comment: how stupid of me, specially when I used `sout print error` after first one, didn't even see `throw new Exception` :)

Comment: No prob, everyone makes similar mistakes after staring at a screen for so long. :)